# Disable Shrink-to-Fit in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

By the default IE is enable `Shrink-to-Fit`. The user not happy about that when they printed a page. It's get data all of the web. But they need only at they seen.

**Shrink-to-Fit**

[image: Shrink-to-Fit]

**By disable Shrink-to-Fit**

[image]

I've done just tell the user to setting by manual.

Have anyway to disabled by using javascript or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try jQuery Print Library;

http://www.swhistlesoft.com/blog/2011/08/05/1411-a-jquery-print-library-that-fixes-the-ie7-shrink-to-fit-issue